# Friends phone keeps rebooting & other problems

Tags: troubleshooting

A friends phone keeps rebooting, & when it does it resets their theme to the default theme. A couple times it has gotten stuck on the bootscreen requiring a battery pull to fix it. Just now after opening google photos which they have been using for a long time without any problems a popup suddenly appeared asking for permissions to access photos & wouldn't allow access with clicking allow. The phone is a Galaxy On5.

Comment: The phone is pretty old and has only 1.5GB RAM. For modern apps this not much. Make sure to disable everything that costs unnecessary RAM like animated background, high-res background image, lots of widgets. Also think about using more "light" apps (Google, Facebook and others provide "light" editions that work better on older devices).

Comment: I just had to factory reset it using the recovery (hold volume down+power+home). For light apps Hermit is good.

Comment: ^ volume up+power+home.